# Is this species scientifically plausible?

Tags: internal-consistency, creature-design, aliens, sea-creatures

**Homeworld**

Zyns have evolved on ocean moon  of Ctalul, the single major moon of gas giant Darstan which orbits the orange dwarf Verrstbirt. Ctalul was once an icy planet with an unstable orbit until it was captured by its parent gravity and when the gas giant has migrated in habitable zone, the world has become molten.

Ctalul orbits its parent in 38.793 earth days and has a local solar day of 35h53m39s.36.  Ctalulian atmosphere is thiner than earth (0.99 atm) and it composed of nitrogen, oxygen,argon and water vapours. The climate of this world is eternal spring-like and is a low gravity (0.25374 g). Being a waterworld without any solid surface, Ctalul has abundant floating vegetation which function as a food and shelter for native flying fauna.

**Biology**

Zyns are an aquatic race resembling earth cephalopods.  Zyns have twelve tentacles which all can be used to manipulate objects.  Zyns have the best eyesight of all sentient species, they are capable to see visible spectrum to humans and different frequencies of radio waves,infrared spectrum,ultraviolet rays and X-rays and because of this they are formidable enemies able to shoot their weapons with a very high precision.

Unlike their earth counterparts, Zyns have a very centralized nervous system. Zyns are able to generate and sustain electric fields used to attack prey or to defend against predators. The electric fields can be also used to generate bioluminescence which can be used as form of long range communication.

**Society and government**

Zyn are an hive minded species, the queens aren't leaders, they are just the female reproductive system of the hive.  Barons, fertile males, form the governing bodies and male reproduvtive system of Zyns.  Workers are infertile females who do all manual labour,scientific research and engineering for the hive.  Soldiers are infertile males which form the military of Zyns, they are strongest of all Zyns and come in two flavours, aquatic and aerial.

Zyn workers have  symbotic relationship with plants from Cenpolla genus.  The plants offer room for metalurgy and a liquid that strenghten the electric field generated by Zyns, while the Zyns offer the plants the minerals from metalurgy waste and help them by making pollination of their flowers.

Zyns curently suffer from a mysterious disease that severly reduce the number of workers born. Since Zyn robotics aren't as efficient as those of other species, the only logical solution to compesate for the small number of workers was enslavement of other sentient species.

Zyns implement control chips in their slaves in order to keep them in line, these chips are known to cause severe headaches when a wearer display some rebellious feeling, the migraines can lead to mental illness and suicide.  Slaves are given the right to keep their native technology.

Comment: Which bit are you asking about? Their physical abilities and evolution, their culture, their technology or their planets position?

Comment: Can you clarify the two different g?  Ctalulian atmosphere is thiner than earth (0.99 g) and it composed of nitrogen, oxygen,argon and water vapours. The climate of this world is eternal spring-like and is a low gravity (0.25374 g).

Comment: @LordKvasir What makes you assume that if you specify the length of a day of this planet to 7 decimal places this helps us to deduce the characteristics of alien life, with alien heredity, in an alien star system, with an alien evolutionary history — alien here meaning "unknown/mysterious/presumed to be different form Earth's ditto"? You have essentially asked: "I have pair of green dice, with yellow dots. The green is Pantone 15-0343 TPG Greenery and the yellow is 13-0755 Primrose Yellow, with a layer of clear over it. If I throw them, what is the result?"

Answer (score 2):

I would say it’s broadly a feasible arrangement. But I do have some serious concerns with some of the details. Not necessarily show stoppers but worthy of some further clarification or explanation.

**Alien nature of a water world sapient species**
There is no reason to suppose that a sapient species could not develop under water, but there are difficulties. It might be tempting to think conceptually of the Zyn as a sort of aquatic creature with a human brain and special abilities. But I don’t think they would be even remotely like us. To make this realistic a lot of work would be needed to identify these differences to make a story believable. Why would they want any artefacts at all? Humans needed them for protection from the environment and predators initialy, but the Zyn seem to be very powerfully equipped already. You might want to give further thought to all the things they lack or don’t have enough of that they need. These things would be useful in building a picture of Zyn motivation.

**Availability of metals**
How do the Zyn acquire their metals? Presumably not by any sort of furnace based process on an all water world. Metals can be refined electrically but doing so underwater would be challenging without sophisticated equipment, so how did the Zyn first acquire metals?

**Hive minded**
Are the Zyn colony forming creature like bees where females have two copies of each chromosome, but males have just one copy (haplodiploid)? Or are they more human like where both sexes have two copies of each chromosome (diploid)? This would have major implications for how they behaved. Assuming that Zyn biology is at least vaguely similar to that on Earth, which given the two sexes I assume it is.

**X-ray vision**
It would be difficult to design an eye to see X-rays and it would be unlikely to develop as such radiation would be filtered out by the water except near the surface. Radio waves also do not pass through water to any great extent.

Answer (score 0):

Electric fields how? This feature, in my opinion, needs some elaboration. If they can use this field to protect themselves and hunt for food, why do they need weapons?

What made them evolve to a more sapient species? What are their weapons? Are they bipedal or do they move on their 12 appendages? How do they react to environmental changes? Do they need clothing or armor? How come there are 2 distinct types of this species? (Flying and aquatic) How do they invade and enslave other species? Are these sapient other species on that planet or are they interstellar?

If you already have answers to these questions that are sound and canonical with the rest, then sure. They seem alright.

Comment: They produce the electric field like an electric eel produce it. Their technology is focused on strengthening their electric field and bioluminescence. They evolved to sentience by the need to outsmart their predators, some are immune to electrical shocks. Their weapons  amplify electric shock produced by Zyn bodies. They aren't bipedal. The react to change in their environment by hiding in deep ocean. Their wear armours when invade a terrestrial species homeworld. The reason for two types of soldiers is their two types of predators. The discovered space travel in 43 AD, long before humans.

Answer (score 0):

I can only say something about the biology, and there are some questionable things.

I do wonder what you mean with the centralized nervous system? The nervous system includes all sorts of signaling including pain and movement of muscles. If you mean with a centralized nervous system that the entire nervous system is for example in the brain only, they would not be able to move or feel pain, as there are no nerves or neurons in the rest of the body to transmit signals.

About the bioluminescence, if you meant to use the same mechanism as bioluminescence on earth it is not generated by electricity. But through [chemical reactions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bioluminescence#Chemical_mechanism). Using electricity for bioluminescence would pose another problem as light through electricity will generate heat, which would basically mean they would cook themselves

Comment: Some chemical reactions also produce heat.

Comment: Ah yes, but the reactions that produce bioluminescence in animals provide no or a neglectable amount of heat.

Answer (score 0):

Ctalul is too close to Darstan to have a day that's different from its orbital period -- it will be tidally locked. For example, Iapetus is tidally locked to Saturn despite being much further away, with an orbital period of 79 days.

Comment: Darstan is comparable to Neptune.

Comment: Neptune doesn't have any moons at a distance matching Ctalul -- there's nothing between Triton with an orbital period of 6 days (and of course tidally locked) and Nereid with an orbital period of 360 days (and not tidally locked). Iapetus and Titan are the best analogues we have in our solar system, and they're both tidally locked.